# Pillow: Create RGBA image from palette

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I have a RGBA palette and a mode='P' image. I want to create a RGBA image from them.

I can get it to work with RGB but not RGBA.

Here's an attempt where I want a blue circle on a transparent background:

```
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImagePalette

palette = ImagePalette.ImagePalette('RGBA', [0,0,0,0, 0,0,255,255])
# palette = ImagePalette.ImagePalette('RGB', [0,0,0, 0,0,255])

labels = Image.new('P', (100,100))
drawer = ImageDraw.Draw(labels)
drawer.ellipse(((25,25),(75,75)), 1)

labels.putpalette(palette)
out = labels.convert('RGBA')
# out = labels.convert('RGB')
out.save('out.png','PNG')
```

I just get black image.
Using the RGB lines I get a blue circle on a black background.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not certain what you are trying to do, nor what is going wrong, but the following should enable you to crated a palette-alpha image and draw in it with 2 colours:

```
from PIL import Image

# Create a new palette image
labels = Image.new('P', (100,100))

# Push an RGBA palette into it, Red, Green, Blue, 253*Black
labels.putpalette([255,0,0,255, 0,255,0,255, 0,0,255,255, *(253*[0,0,0])], rawmode='RGBA')

# Get a drawing context and draw ellipse using palette entries 0 and 1
drawer = ImageDraw.Draw(labels)
drawer.ellipse([(25,25),(75,75)], fill=1, outline=0)

labels.save('result.png')
```

[image]

Comment: I had an old version of Pillow and got "ValueError: unrecognized raw mode". I see that putpalette with "RGBA" mode didn't work until Pillow 8.1.0 (2021-01-02) https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/pull/5089